# Removing multiple substrings from a text with index

Tags: python-3.x

I have a long text, and I am trying to remove multiple substrings using start and end index. The problem here is that when I remove the first substring from the original text, the rest of the start and end indexes will be invalid. what is the most efficient way to do this?

```
def remove_substrings(text, indexes):
    '''
        indexes is a list containing start and end indexes.
        indexes = ["3 5", "7 8"]
    '''

    return text
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont remove the substring right away, instead, use another variable and append substrings to it.

```
def remove_substrings(text, indexes):
    '''
        indexes is a list containing start and end indexes.
        indexes = ["3 5", "7 8"]
    '''
    newText = ""
    i = 0

    for index in indices:
        j = int(index[0])
        newText += text[i:j]
        i = int(index[-1]) +  1
    return newText
```

Example for above code-
text: 'abcdef....z'(all alphabets of english)
indices: ["3 5", "7 8"]
expected output : all alphabets except 'd,e,f'(index:3 to 5) and 'h,i'(index 7 to 8).

The string newText will append values from a upto c in first iteration, then g in 2nd and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of removing substrings from `left to right`, remove them from `right to left`. This approach will ensure unchanged indices on the `left` side. Though it will solve your problem, there can be more efficient ways to do that.

Answer (score 1):

```
def remove_substrings(text, indexes):
    '''
        indexes is a list containing start and end indexes.
        indexes = ["3 5", "7 8"]
    '''
    int_indexes = []
    for idx in indexes:
        s1,s2 = idx.split()
        int_indexes.append([int(s1), int(s2)])
    int_indexes.sort()
    int_indexes.reverse()
    for idx in int_indexes:
        text = text[0:idx[0]] + text[idx[1]+1:]
    return text
```

If your indexes are not sorted you will have to convert them to integer first.
try with

```
text = "0123456789012345"
print(remove_substrings(text, ["3 5", "10 12", "7 8"]))
```

The first for loop can be replaced by list commprehension as follows:

`int_indexes = [[int(idx.split()[0]),int(idx.split()[1])] for idx in indexes]`